# What's missing to run Next Radio, and how can I get/install it?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4, fm-radio

I've got a Samsung Galaxy S4 (Verizon), currently running Lollipop as provided by the carrier -- not rooted.  Verizon has apparently recently begun to allow NextRadio to run on some of their phones, including the S7 and S7 Edge, but the app (which plays FM radio off the air) still reports something about required software missing when I try to install it.  I presume, at this point, that this is a missing driver or similar that would normally be supplied in an update from the provider, but of course Verizon is barely updating security on Lollipop and S4 platforms at this time.

Is there any way to get the required driver on my phone so I can use NextRadio or some other FM radio app?  Ideally without rooting the phone, but if rooting and updating to a newer Android version is required, a recommendation on rooting app or method would be appreciated as well.  If it matters, I run Kubuntu 14.04 on my computer, though I also have Kubuntu 16.04 installed; there's not a single Windows machine in my house.

Comment: Does the error message mention any missing software specifically? As far as rooting concerned, if you find a rom and a recovery image for your device, most instructions are for odin on windows. On 16.04 you can install `sudo apt-get install heimdall-flash heimdall-flash-frontend` to use instead of odin. You should be able to find tutorials on how to use `heimdall`. Use the command `heimdall-frontend` to start up the GUI.

Comment: And here is some discussion which mentions moble odin. I've never used it.http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/help/how-to-odin-linux-t1912921

Comment: Okay, so I can (probably) root my S4 with Mobile Odin or use heimdall from Kubuntu to flash a ROM on the S4.  Now I need to go ask another question about a rooted S4.